Why do we ignore the horizontal components of a pin when the machine is in symmetry?
I have the following homework where we need to find the reaction force at pin C. 
If we were to abide by the solution manual, we would get the exact same answer as provided by the answer key if we do not have the horizontal component of pin C. However, I do not see any reason to ignore the horizontal component of C, as it would make the system not in static condition as seen in this free body diagram of member DCB; where the force $F_{DF}$ has horizontal component.


Since part b only asks us to find the normal forces at A and B, we can take moments about C and so ignore all forces through C.

I don't see why this was closed as homework as it seems to be asking for help with a conceptual issue.

Yes, you are right but consider this:
The horizontal component of the force $F_{C,hor}$ will generate an acceleration if the object is not fixed at $A,B$. But if the object is fixed, friction at $A,B$ should balance out to cancel the acceleration or the whole system(forklift and the wooden panel will move horizontally due to that). If friction is low, the forklift will slip.
But when I am asked to calculate the force supported by $C$, I would assume that the friction is enough and the forklift will properly carry the wooden panel and I can safely ignore the horizontal force. The job it is supposed to do!
